# Sistering stingers to convert stairs from closed to open stinger

Tags: framing, stairs, renovation

I have a set of existing closed stringer stairs with a full wall on the left and half wall on the right.  I am looking to remove the full wall and modify both sides of the stairs to an open style.  I am only changing the bottom 5 treads.  In doing so, I will be loosing a good portion of the existing stringer on both sides.  Is it possible to sister the stringers with 2x12, cut to the same rise and run.  I would Timber-lok the stringers together, as well as Timber-lok thru to the studs where I can[image]

Comment: Is the full wall load bearing? If it is, you'll be looking at a much larger project than you've anticipated.

Comment: @Tester101 - I think you are really on to something regarding the load bearing wall issue. From all the houses that I've seen with stairs as pictured near the central line of the house the adjacent wall is very very often load bearing.